# Will a doubled P-trap cause problems if it has a vent between the traps?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, drain-waste-vent, p-trap

Our plumber discovered that the drain pipe under our bathroom sink (*which is done properly with a P-trap and vent*) has a **second** P-trap down in the crawl space, which is incorrect.

I've been researching this and understand that having two in-line P-traps can cause drainage problems because air gets trapped between the two traps and water can't push it out.

However, in this case, there is a vent between the two traps, so I think that particular problem may be ameliorated. It's still done incorrectly though, and I'm trying to assess the risks.

What other problems could this second P-trap cause?

[image]

Comment: It could be a pain to get a snake down that line. Is there something else on that line or any reason for the trap?

Comment: settling of crud causing a clog

Comment: I had this in a previous house.  It was 1941 construction.   I could only guess that the underfloor trap was the only trap when originally installed.   When an under-sink trap was later installed, given the vent, the effort to remove a (now) very old cast iron trap inside the basement ceiling was "deprioritized".   Just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

- Debris is more likely to settle in the second trap due to lower drain velocity at that point
- It's more difficult to clear debris there because you can't conveniently disassemble the trap
- System cleanout with an auger is impeded by the extra trap bends, which tend to be sharper than other underground bends

Comment: So the result of those issues would be slow draining or a completely clogged drain that is potentially impossible to clear with an auger?

Comment: Yes, though the actual likelihood of a problem has more to do with type and condition of plumbing.